# How to set EULA file of WiX custom bootstrapper?

Tags: wix, burn

When using WiX standard bootstrapper I can set EULA file by following [this](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/wixstdba/). But how can I do the same thing with my custom bootstrapper? How can I set EULA file in Bundle.wxs and access it from my c# UI project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the license file as a `Payload` under the `BootstrapperApplicationRef` just like the [WiX bundle does](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/develop/src/Setup/Bundle/Bundle.wxs):

```
<BootstrapperApplicationRef Id='ManagedBootstrapperApplicationHost'>
    <Payload Name='BootstrapperCore.config' SourceFile='WixBA.BootstrapperCore.config' />

    <Payload SourceFile='WixBA.dll' />
    <Payload SourceFile='..\..\..\License.txt' />
</BootstrapperApplicationRef>
```

Comment: But, how to load it into the rich text control of Bootstrapper UI project?

Comment: You can look at the [WixBA](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/develop/src/Setup/WixBA/InstallationViewModel.cs) to see how it accesses its license file (the LaunchLicense method).  Then you would read the files contents and set the your C# text control's text to the contents using standard C# methods.

Comment: I loaded EULA file in the `BootstrapperApplicationRef` by following [this](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Re-Managed-Bootstrapper-Access-Payload-file-from-WPF-Code-td7586373.html).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you are asking for it but [according to this tutorial](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/wixstdba/wixstdba_license.html), you can set EULA (license) in *WixStandardBootstrapperApplication* example from tutorial:

```
<Bundle>
  <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense">
    <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication
        LicenseFile="path\to\license.rtf"  <!-- HERE -->
        LogoFile="path\to\customlogo.png"/>
  </BootstrapperApplicationRef>
  <Chain>
    ...
  </Chain>
</Bundle>
```